# golang exec.Command execute bash exit status 1

Tags: bash, go, exec

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "rm -rf *")
cmd.Dir = "/root/media/"
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "'rm -rf *' command failed.")
}
```

"err": exit with status 1
I think I am not writing exec.Command correctly, but I cannot fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command that is going to be executed in `bash` should be enclosed with double quote (or single quote), e.g.

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", `"rm -rf *"`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this similar error, I think you need to replace "*" to the absolute path.

Like below:

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "rm -rf <your path>")
```

Not use "*".