# golang exec.Command returns exit status 1 with bash

Tags: go, exec

I am trying to run multiple commands using `bash -c` in `exec.Command`, when i manually run the command, it returns no error the output of command is nil but it's okay. I don't know why it returns `exit status 1` when i run it through golang `exec.Command`.

Here is my code :

```
cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "blkid -o device | grep -v part | grep /dev/mapper")
_ = cmd.Wait()
stdout, err := cmd.Output()
```

I even tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860014/13129019) answer from another question, but it also didn't worked out.
The important thing is that when i run command on a vm where output is not nil the command executes successfully, but when i tried this on `Centos` where output is nil it failed.

Comment: @Inian i need to run command in one line, and have to keep the code simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have to pass the command in the string slice.
Use this instead -

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("bash",strings.Fields("-c blkid -o device | grep -v part | grep /dev/mapper"))
stdout, err := cmd.Output()
```

Comment: cannot use type `[] string` as type `string`

Comment: @KashifKhan0771 Sorry my bad, I have updated my answer. Please have a look